# Get numbers from url as string in php using get method

Tags: php

I have a URL structure as **example.com/tag/abcd**

I have tag.php where I have used:

```
$e=$_GET['t'];
$e=str_replace("-", " ", $e);
```

But whenever there is a number in place of abcd it produces 500 error. Moreover, if there is **abcd-12** then I am getting only 'abcd' through GET method.

500 Error is produced when URL is like **example.com/tag/123**

Here is htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-zA-Z-]+) tag.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I am unable to see `$_GET['t']` value in Your URL

Comment: What is the error you get when you have a number?

Comment: Maybe we should see your .htaccess or whatever you use to convert that nice url into something where `$_GET` would get set

Comment: Added Htaccess code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure of what you are trying to do but this should do the trick :

```
$e=strval($_GET['t']);
$e=str_replace("-", " ", $e);
```

**Edit :**

Okay, you added your rewrite rule, now the problem is clear :

```
[a-zA-Z-]
```

This matches only characters and -, not numbers.

Try

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

I recommend you this site to visualize your regex :
https://regexper.com/#%5Ba-zA-Z0-9-%5D

Comment: Tried this, When I put **/tag/windows-10** in the URL. I am getting only **windows** from the URL.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I forget about htaccess thing. Thanks for your help.